# Matlab code to save portion as ASCII and remaining as integer

Tags: matlab, ascii

I have a matrix, in which all the values are between 0 and 1 (e.g.: 0.003,0.005 ...), except for the the last column, which are integers (e.g.: 1,2 3, ...). When I save it to a text file,  it converts all values to ASCII format. I need to do the following:

a) Save the matrix to a text file with the same values. i.e., integers as it is and other values as it is.

b) Or I have to keep the values in the text file as ASCII except the last column, which should be in the text file as integers itself.

Comment: I don't get it, what output do you expect? What encoding do you mean with "as the inegers itself"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you mean something like this:

```
A = [rand(4,5) randi(10,4,1)];

fid = fopen('TEST.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fid, [repmat('%f ', 1,size(A,2)-1) '%d\r\n'], A');
fclose(fid);
```

contents of `TEST.txt`:

```
0.709365 0.655098 0.959744 0.751267 0.890903 2
0.754687 0.162612 0.340386 0.255095 0.959291 3
0.276025 0.118998 0.585268 0.505957 0.547216 9
0.679703 0.498364 0.223812 0.699077 0.138624 3
```

Comment: @ Rody - I need the same output as you specified above. i run the code , but output is a single line. Not the one as you mentioned above . any help would be appreciated .

Comment: @SarathRNair: could be a Windows/Linux/Mac newline issue (see [the wiki on newline representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations))...What OS are you using, and what tool do you use to view the text file?

Comment: @ Rody - Hey it is working in Wordpad. But in notepad it showed as a single line. thanks alot Rody. Wonderful. I dint get the logic behind it. Can you please tell me that .

Comment: @SarathRNair: See also help `fprintf`. The important thing to note is that `fprintf` uses the format string in a 'vectorized' way, meaning, if there are more elements in the input array than specified in the format string, it re-uses that same format for each new batch of elements in the input array, until they are all written to file. Note also that you have to *transpose* the array, because in MATLAB, the default reading direction is column-major.

Comment: @SarathRNair: yes, so, if you want to view it correctly in notepad, you'll have to use the Windows-specific version of the newline: `\r\n` (instead of just `\n`).

Comment: Wow. Thanks alot for the information. I have not deal much with texts in matlab . Wonderful piece of work and wonderful explanation . Thanks alot .